# Intercepting DataContext object creation in Entity Framework to wire up events

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to wire up some events with my Entity Framework classes, to do this I need to 'intercept' the retrieval of these classes from the DBContext.

I've tried doing this at a repository level, when someone get's objects from a DBSet, before passing the entity on I go through and add an event listener.

However, lazy loading throws a spanner in the works here.

I found a way to intercept queries using IDbCommandInterceptor, is there any way to intercept the entity framework object creation itself, or even just the lazy loading, so I can inject dependencies, or register events?

Comment: Ah, may have found something with the "ObjectMaterialized" event.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `DbContext` you can register to the `ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized` event. You can subscribe in the constructor to make it simple.

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += onObjectMaterialized;
```

The signature is relatively simple

```
void onObjectMaterialized(object sender, ObjectMaterializedEventArgs e) {
  // your code here
}
```

And now the code knows when objects are created by the EF DbContext.

Comment: Spent a fair while googling looking at interceptors and ObjectProxies, then I just stumbled upon this just as everyone answered! Thanks. Exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

If you dig a little deeper in DbContext, you'l find the ObjectContext, which has an event for this (`ObjectMaterialized`)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectmaterialized(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is wondering, for EF CORE, we have the IMaterializationInterceptor

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#simple-actions-on-entity-creation

Comment: Please consider adding a small usage example, or explain how it's better than or adds to existing solutions. Looking through the linked docs it seems to just be generalized event interception, just on a slightly different event than what OP used.